# weblogic datasource in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, resources, weblogic, datasource

i'm trying to understand how to getting weblogic datasource in jsp in my simple web application (assembled in test.war and deployed on weblogic application server)

i'm gоt working version of this, it make me do not less mandatory 4 steps (5-th
 proposed step - import necessary classes with <%@ page import direcitve):

- **on weblogic set jndi name, in my case**

  jdbc/test
- **on jsp page make jsp declaration of field with @Resource annotation**

  < %!

  @Resource(name="jdbc/test")

  private DataSource ds;

  % >
- **on jsp page in scriptlet get context and do lookup by string java:comp/env/jdbc/test in my case**

  ```
   ctx = new InitialContext();

  //ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");

  //thanks Display Name is missing

  ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/test");
  ```
- **add in web.xml these elements**

  ```
    <resource-ref>

       <res-ref-name>jdbc/test</res-ref-name>

       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>

    </resource-ref>
  ```

Each step is necessary, it's my working version, I broke my head until I got this version.

I'm testing it, and I'll try to remove each step, but my datasource is not work after that.

I read many articles and answers, but nowhere i never met information, which said that all of steps is mandatory. Many of them said only about: annotate with @Resource your field for example and all be working. But it is wrong!

This version is working, but different yet is not working! (i'll try also add some tags in weblogic.xml)

So i want to ask you: all I doing and understand right?

What's features?

Can you give me some links, where I can detail read about this?

Comment: Have you tried using `ctx.lookup("jdbc/test");` instead of `ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");`? You do not need the "java:comp/env/" at the start. Any errors in your weblogic server log file?

Comment: @Display Name is missing   - thank you for your comment, i'll try it and it work fine, i don't know how it does not work formerly. i'll don't understand where i must see weblogic log - i'll see it in file named like this C:\...servers\myserver\logs\myserverer.log, but not found something interesting. it's very good that i don't must write java:comp/env/jdbc/test  and write  only jdbc/test instead.  but can i do not do it generally? or can i do not doing other steps, e.g. don't write resource-ref tag in web.xml? i want to do only 2 first steps, it wil be great, can i do it somehow?